# PHP pass objects from the page to a socket

Tags: php, sockets, object, websocket

I am incorporating functions to an existing platform with its functional MVC model. The fact is that I am working in the chat and for this I use [PHP Sockets](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.sockets.php)

I can not change anything in the structure of the MVC, but I need to bring to my `socket.php` file two objects that are in `index.php`

These objects contain sensitive information that should not be visible to the user. `index.php` is located at `root_folder/subfolder/index.php` and `socket.php` is located at `root_folder/another_subfolder/third_subfolder/socket.php`

**index.php**

```
<?php
...

$object1 = new Object1();
$object2 = new Object2();
```

**socket.php**

```
<?php
...

class Socket extends MyOwnSocketClass{

    protected function onmessage($message){

        // I need these two objects here

    }

}

...

$socket = new Socket($host, $port);
try { $socket->run(); }
catch (Exception $e) { $socket->stdout($e->getMessage()); }
```

Then, from the terminal I use `php -q root_folder/another_subfolder/third_subfolder/socket.php` to start the socket, everything works fine and the client side connects without problems. But at the same time I tried to bring those two objects from the `index.php` to `socket.php` ...

**socket.php**

```
require '../subfolf/index.php'; // Error failed open stream
require 'root_folder/subfolder/index.php'; // Undefined variable $object1
/*Using sessions*/ $_SESSION['object1']; // Undefined index object1
/*Using globals*/ $_GLOBALS['object1']; // Call to method in null
```

In summary, I can not use require, I can not use $ _SESSION, I can not upload levels in directories using ../ and if I intance the socket in the index.php the page is loading infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `index.php` is actually a page that outputs things.  In that case, when you `require()` it, it's sending its output and that's why it's breaking your stream.

If you have some sort of shared object/class, you should put it in its own file that you can `require()` in both `index.php` and `socket.php` as-needed.  That file shouldn't output anything... it should only contain the PHP code you need to include in both contexts.